# Unable to go from pandas to dask dataframe, memory error

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-distributed

I have a pandas dataframe that has 7 million records, I am trying to create a dask dataframe but I keep running into memory issues.

Code used:

```
dd_test = dd.from_pandas(df_lookup_table, npartitions=3)
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\venv\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\io\io.py", line 181, in from_pandas
    name = name or ('from_pandas-' + tokenize(data, chunksize))
  File "C:\Users\user\venv\lib\site-packages\dask\base.py", line 600, in tokenize
    return md5(str(tuple(map(normalize_token, args))).encode()).hexdigest()
  File "C:\Users\user\venv\lib\site-packages\dask\utils.py", line 413, in __call__
    return meth(arg, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\venv\lib\site-packages\dask\base.py", line 710, in normalize_dataframe
    return list(map(normalize_token, data))
  File "C:\Users\user\venv\lib\site-packages\dask\utils.py", line 413, in __call__
    return meth(arg, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\venv\lib\site-packages\dask\base.py", line 734, in normalize_array
    x.flat]))
MemoryError
```

I was able to create a dask dataframe with a smaller dataframe. How can I create a dask dataframe from this pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of dask is to be able to process data which doesn't fit into memory. In this case, you are loading the data-set into memory first, before passing it to dask. Instead, you should load the data directly with dask. For example, if you used `pandas.read_csv`, you should switch this to `dask.dataframe.read_csv`.

Comment: I am not reading the file from a csv, I am exporting it from Aster Teradata and I am unable to read it directly into dask since the driver for aster does not exist in sqlalchemy. I am however able to read the sql table as a pandas table using pyodbc but this does not work for dask. This is why I am trying to go from pandas to dask.

Comment: a) why do you want to use dask? b) `dask.dataframe.read_sql` may well be all you need, or c) please read up on `dask.delayed` and `dd.from_delayed` and consider how you can partition your query.

Comment: "does not exist in sqlalchemy" - sorry misread this, thought it *did* exist, so `read_sql` won't work. However, please consider question a) before putting too much effort into suggestion c)